# Infinite and finite representation of the same real number

Tags: proof-explanation, real-numbers, decimal-expansion

I'm reading The Foundations of Mathematics and trying to understand the proof of the finite and infinite representation of the same real number.

---

For example, if a number x has two different decimal expansions, then, without loss in generality, we can take $x = a_0 · a_1 . . . a_{n–1}a_n . . . = a_0 · a_1 . . . a_{n-1}b_n . . .$ where $a_n < b_n$.

Multiply through by $10^n$ to get $a_0a_1 . . . a_{n–1}a_n · a_{n+1} . . . = a_0a_1 . . . a_{n–1}b_n · a_{n+1}. . .$ where $a_n < b_n$.

Subtracting the whole number $a_0a_1 . . . a_{n–1}a_n$ gives $0 · a_{n+1} . . . = k · b_{n+1}$ . . . where $k = b_{n+1} – a_{n+1} > 0$ is a positive integer.

But the first decimal is $0 · a_{n+1} . . . < 0 · 999 . . . ≤ 1$ and the second exceeds the positive integer k. So they can be equal only if $k
= 1$ and both decimals represent the same limiting value 1. In this case, $a_{n+1} = a_{n+2} = · · · = 9, b_{n+1} = b_{n+2} = · · · = 0$ and $b_n = a_n + 1$.

---

Specifically, how do they produce $0 · a_{n+1} . . . = k · b_{n+1}$ . . . where $k = b_{n+1} – a_{n+1} > 0$ is a positive integer? Shouldn't it be $0 · a_{n+1} . . . = k · a_{n+1} . . .$ where $k = b_{n} – a_{n}$ ?

Also which decimals are meant by "the first" and "the second"?

[Link to the full explanation](https://books.google.be/books?id=KtETDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=But%20the%20first%20decimal%20is%200%20%C2%B7%20an%2B1%20.%20.%20.%20%3C%200%20%C2%B7%20999%20.%20.%20.%20%E2%89%A4%201%20and%20the%20second%20exceeds%20the%20positive%20integer%20k.%20So%20they%20can%20be%20equal%20only%20if%20k%20%3D%201%20and%20both%20decimals%20represent%20the%20same%20limiting%20value%201.%20In%20this%20case,%20an%2B1%20%3D%20an%2B2%20%3D%20%C2%B7%20%C2%B7%20%C2%B7%20%3D%209,%20bn%2B1%20%3D%20bn%2B2%20%3D%20%C2%B7%20%C2%B7%20%C2%B7%20%3D%200%20and%20bn%20%3D%20an%20%2B%201.&source=bl&ots=y8B2rsGOGm&sig=ACfU3U2q6xHY8w2P1opYR9DRv6huR6TDWw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihyJu935XqAhVKzqQKHRKkCmoQ6AEwAHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: I suspect that, when you wrote $a_0a_1\ldots a_{n–1}a_n.a_{n+1} \ldots= a_0a_1\ldots a_{n–1}b_n.a_{n+1}\ldots$, what you meant was $a_0a_1\ldots a_{n–1}a_n.a_{n+1} \ldots= a_0a_1\ldots a_{n–1}b_n.b_{n+1}\ldots$

Comment: That's exactly how the explanation is written in the book (check the link). Except if it's a typo...

Comment: My guess is that, yes, it is a typo.

Comment: Would you also then say that $k=b_n–a_n$? And the second part of the question, by showing that $0 · a_{n+1} . . . = k · b_{n+1. . .}$ it is shown that $0 · a_{n+1} . . . < 0 · 999. . .$ is not true and it must be  $0 · a_{n+1} . . . = 0 · 999. . . = 1$? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: It must be $10^{n-1}$. Jose pointed out the typos. The proof shows that the only case where the expansion is not unique is if there is a terminating representation, and in this case, there are exactly two ways. If we rule out the period $0.\bar 9$, the expansion is always unique.